# How to check collision between the player and a specific TileBase object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a couple of tilebase variables that are set using the unity inspector:

```
public TileBase obstacle; //obstacle tile
public TileBase spikes; //instant death tile
```

I'm using OnCollisionEnter2D in a script that is set to the tilemap asset.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Collision", 1);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to detect when the player has collided with the spikes TileBase as that should trigger a game over. The asset name that is set to the spikes variable through the inspector is also called Spikes or Spikes (Tile) in the palette.

I tried using adding collision detection to a script that is used on the player asset to check what objects it collides with

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name);
}
```

But all it comes back with is the name of the tilemap.

Comment: I haven't worked with 2D in Unity before, but I believe every object should be able to have a Tag set. Normally this is what tags are used for. Try setting a tag to it and accessing col.gameObject.tag.

Comment: Sadly I can only tag the Tilemap and not the individual tiles within it. I'm fairly certain I would be able to get it working with 2 individual tilemaps overlaid over each other, but that way there would be fair amount of redundant code and just probable problems with 2 objects appearing in the same tile space.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add Layers to your objects. An easy example is to add a "TileBase" or "Tile" Layer to your TileBase objects.

You can then allow your Player to only collide with certain things and NOT your tilemap. See the collision matrix for this.

Then alter your code like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    var tilebase = col.GetComponent<TileBase>();
    if (tilebase != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(tilebase.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```